# MySQL: Multi Query not executing 2nd and 3rd appended queries

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, multi-query

So I am trying to send a long appended sql query that will populate a temporary table. Based on the table I am populating an array that stores the different values from the table.

The first insert statement runs perfectly fine, and inserts correctly to the array. The next two appended queries do not seem to be populating the array.

After doing some error checking I have verified that the statements do have the correct values on the end of the query.

NOTE: username, password, and database have been removed from the code

Any and all help is much appreciated.

```
<?php
session_start();
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "";
$password   = "";
$db         = "";

$conn       = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed:" . $conn->connect_error);
}

$courseID = $_GET['id'];
echo $courseID;

$studentID = $_SESSION['memberID'];
echo $studentID;

$maketemp = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TempCourseProfile (
CourseID int not null,
CourseName varchar(100),
CourseDescription varchar(200),
CourseObjectives varchar(200),
CourseStartDate date,
CourseEndDate date,
InstructorFirstName varchar(50),
InstructorLastName varchar(50),
PRIMARY KEY(CourseID))";

if($conn->query($maketemp) === TRUE){
echo "you win";
} 
else {
echo "you lose";
}

$query = "INSERT INTO TempCourseProfile(CourseID, CourseName, CourseDescription, CourseObjectives)
SELECT CourseID, CourseName, CourseDescription, CourseObjectives FROM Course     WHERE CourseID = $courseID;";

$query .= "INSERT INTO TempCourseProfile(CourseStartDate, CourseEndDate)
Select CI.ClassStartDate, CI.ClassEndDate From CourseInSemester CI JOIN     ClassSchedule CS on CI.CourseInSemesterID = CS.CourseInSemesterID WHERE     CS.StudentID = $studentID AND CI.CourseID = $courseID;";

$query .= "INSERT INTO TempCourseProfile(InstructorFirstName, InstructorLastName)
    Select M.FirstName, M.LastName from Member M JOIN CourseInSemester CI ON CI.TeacherID = M.MemberID JOIN ClassSchedule CS ON CS.CourseInSemesterID = CI.CourseInSemesterID WHERE CI.CourseID = $courseID AND CS.StudentID = $studentID;";

echo $query;
if ($conn->multi_query($query)) {
do{
    echo "added";

}while($conn->next_result());
} else {
echo "failed to create temp" . $conn->error;
}

$tmparray = array();
$sql      = "SELECT * FROM TempCourseProfile where CourseID = $courseID";
//$result   = $conn->query($sql);
if($result = $conn->query($sql)){
while ($r = $result->fetch_array()) {
$e                      = array();
$e['CourseID']          = $r['CourseID'];
$e['CourseName']         = $r['CourseName'];
$e['CourseDescription']          = $r['CourseDescription'];
$e['CourseObjectives']             = $r['CourseObjectives'];
$e['CourseStartDate']         = $r['CourseStartDate'];
$e['CourseEndDate']    = $r['CourseEndDate'];
$e['InstructorFirstName']   = $r['InstructorFirstName'];
$e['InstructorLastName'] = $r['InstructorLastName'];
array_push($tmparray, $e);
}

} else {
echo $conn->error;
}


echo json_encode($tmparray);

?>
```

The issue has to deal with the values of `$e['CourseStartDate']`, `$e['CourseEndDate']`, `$e['InstructorFirstName']`, `$e['InstructorLastName']`

Comment: You have `CourseID int not null`/`PRIMARY KEY(CourseID)`, but your 2nd/3rd queries don't have a `CourseID` value, and since it is not an `auto_increment` they are probably failing due to `duplicate key` errors.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not use multi_query. Run your queries one by one.
2. ALWAYS make mysqli report its errors. It's no use to ask people what's wrong with your database - they cannot know. Only your database can tell you for certain.

So make your code this way

```
$queries = ["CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TempCourseProfile (
CourseID int not null,
CourseName varchar(100),
CourseDescription varchar(200),
CourseObjectives varchar(200),
CourseStartDate date,
CourseEndDate date,
InstructorFirstName varchar(50),
InstructorLastName varchar(50),
PRIMARY KEY(CourseID))"];

$queries[] = "INSERT INTO TempCourseProfile(CourseID, CourseName, CourseDescription, CourseObjectives)
SELECT CourseID, CourseName, CourseDescription, CourseObjectives FROM Course     WHERE CourseID = $courseID;";

$queries[] = "INSERT INTO TempCourseProfile(CourseStartDate, CourseEndDate)
Select CI.ClassStartDate, CI.ClassEndDate From CourseInSemester CI JOIN     ClassSchedule CS on CI.CourseInSemesterID = CS.CourseInSemesterID WHERE     CS.StudentID = $studentID AND CI.CourseID = $courseID;";

$queries[] = "INSERT INTO TempCourseProfile(InstructorFirstName, InstructorLastName)
    Select M.FirstName, M.LastName from Member M JOIN CourseInSemester CI ON CI.TeacherID = M.MemberID JOIN ClassSchedule CS ON CS.CourseInSemesterID = CI.CourseInSemesterID WHERE CI.CourseID = $courseID AND CS.StudentID = $studentID;";

foreach ($queries as $query) {
    $conn->query($query) or trigger_error($conn->error);
}
```

this code won't echo any useless spam, yet it will report an exact error once it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The reason to use multi_query is very simple. We want to limit communication with database - single request is much faster than 1000 request one by one.

Alternative to multi_query is multiple records in single query.

```
INSERT INTO .. (col1, col2) VALUES (v1.1,v2.1), (v1.2, v2.2), (v1.3, v2.3) ...;
```

But most of all data should be validated before inserting to query.
Many objected oriented data models do it for You based on actual database structure by caching table columns and type:

```
DESCRIBE table;
```

Before any query is executed data prepended to insert/update is compromised with specific column type and format.